# Crossfilter dimension: How to create dimension from static data/json columns instead of particular variables?

Tags: crossfilter

Say I have the following data structure:

```
[
    {columnA: 1, columnB: 2, columnC: 3},
    {columnA: 4, columnB: 5, columnC: 6},
    {columnA: 7, columnB: 8, columnC:9}
]
```

usually you define dimension based on one column:

```
var dimensionA = myCrossFilter.dimension(function(row) {
    return row.columnA;
})
```

and group on that:

```
dc.pieChart("#chart")
    .dimension(dimensionA )
    .group(dimensionA.group )
    .xAxis().ticks(3);
```

How can I define dimension and group them with crossfilter/DC based on the different columns? i.e. if I want to group and show a pieChart by columnA, columnB, and columnC?

Update: when I loop through the data I can get the sum of each column:

```
var a =0, b=0, c=0;
dataSet.forEach(function(d) {
 a += d.a;
 b += d.b;
 c += d.c;
```

}

how to draw the pieChart with the above static data, something like this:

```
dc.pieChart("#chart")
    .dimension(["A", "B", "C"] )
    .group([12, 15, 18] )
    .xAxis().ticks(3);
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what this would mean, to group on those 3 columns. The sum of them? Can you describe in your question what you would like to see happen and what the groups would look like based on the data that you provide in your example?

Comment: Sorry about that as I am learning the package. I'd like to have a pieChart split based on the total of the 3 columns. In the example above the pieChart would have 3 slices, A(12), B(15), C(18).

Comment: I'd suggest you transform your data into a record structure like { columnName: "A", value: 1 } and then use Crossfilter on that. Your dimension would be columnName and your group would be dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.value; })

Comment: I try to avoid that as the data structure is little more complicated than that. I updated the question above. Maybe it is easier now?

Comment: You could use a custom reducer to aggregate a, b, and c all in the same group, and then build a fake group to feed to DC.js. Generally I recommend data transformation before resorting to this if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am not sure I understood what you mean. Can you provide some simple pseduo code, hopefully in the DC/Crossfilter format?

Comment: Best if you could set up a working example on JSFiddle or Codepen - that's the way to make it easiest for people to help you get the code right.

Comment: No - you'll have to set up a working example to make it as quick as possible to help you. Sorry, but I can't spend a ton of time on this, so I need to see working code so that I can easily test my suggestions without having to go back and forth.

Comment: I created a codepen here. First time using it:  http://codepen.io/hzlvaj/pen/mVZZZp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's an updated version of your Codepen that runs and aggregates each column into a group format that dc.js can understand, and displays it as a pie chart: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEXbyW

The key points are that you need to use a custom reducer to aggregate all your values into a single group

```
speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduce(function(p,d) {
      p.a += d.A;
      p.b += d.B;
      p.c += d.C;
      return p;
    }, function(p,d) {
      p.a -= d.A;
      p.b -= d.B;
      p.c -= d.C;
      return p;
    }, function() {
      return { a: 0, b: 0, c:0 }
    });
```

And that you then need to create a fake group that returns the format that dc.js expects in order to build your pie chart

```
var fakeGroup = {
  all: function() { return [
    { key: "A", value: speedSumGroup.top(1)[0].value.a },
    { key: "B", value: speedSumGroup.top(1)[0].value.b },
    { key: "C", value: speedSumGroup.top(1)[0].value.c }
  ]; }
}

chart
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(fakeGroup);
```

As mentioned above, I strongly recommend transforming your data into a format that works better with dc.js and Crossfilter if you are going to use these libraries, rather than going through these sorts of gymnastics to make your data work. Properly transforming your data gives a much simpler result:

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
var data = [ 
    {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3},
    {A: 4, B: 5, C: 6},
    {A: 7, B: 8, C:9}
];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  for(key in d) {
    newData.push({ name: key, value: d[key] });
  }
});

var ndx = crossfilter(newData);
var dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.name; });
var grp = dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.value; });

chart
    .dimension(dim)
    .group(grp);

  chart.render();
```

Transformed example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyeWWa

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Once I see your code, it is obvious that transforming the data is easier.  The catch is that with one data source, a user can click on one chart, and the other charts will be updated automatically based on the filters behind the scene. While with separate "newData", when the piechart is clicked, I need to capture the event and update the original "data" source and redraw the other charts. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool :-) If you can run your other charts off of the transformed data as well, then dc.js will handle the updates. Otherwise, yes, you will need to capture events and handle the updates yourself.

Comment: @EthanJewett Do you happen to have an example of how to handle the update in such a case? I am thinking to use this to create a total pie chart, but would like to have this total (pre-transformed data) respond to when the original data changes (original non-transformed data)

Comment: Not sure I follow. Might make sense to put together a simple example and a new question.

Comment: @EthanJewett I was referring to the last sentence in your comment: `Otherwise, yes, you will need to capture events and handle the updates yourself.`

Comment: Oh, I see. No example off the top of my head, but use https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+on to listen for the "filtered" event and act on it.